# Howto fill combobox with array in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I am struggling with a problem in ExtJS 4...

I have an array like this:

```
[ 2010, 2011,2012 ]
```

And I would like to fill my combobox with these values.
I can set the first value with combobox.setValue() but I want to set several values.
This is my combobox:

```
var combobox = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[name=myBox]')[0];
```

Does someone know how I can populate the combobox with the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this

> Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', { 
>       store: ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Brown', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Black'] 
>   });

Ref: http://skirtlesden.com/articles/extjs-comboboxes-part-1